# query isotope filter add selected css

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I tried to find the answer to this, it's probably quite simple.
I want to add a selected class to the active filter in isotope. Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry : {
      columnWidth : 165
    }
  });


  // filter items when filter link is clicked
  $('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector, animationEngine : "css" });
  return false;


  });
```

my html is:

```
<ul id="filters" >
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Henry">Henry</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".William">South William</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Grafton">Grafton</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Talbot">Talbot</a></li>
</ul>
```

Anyone help please?
thanks
Dave

Answer (score 3):

add the filter you want to be pre-selected as `filter:` `.pre-selected class`

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    filter: '.Grafton',
    masonry : {
        columnWidth : 165
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/ filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
$('#filters a.active').removeClass('active');
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector, animationEngine : "css" });
$(this).addClass('active');
return false;


});
```